# Java Regex pattern to match string with apostrophes

Tags: java, regex, apostrophe

I need to match a pattern to strip the `'s` as well as the ending `'` from words. I've used the regex pattern:

```
(\\w+)('s$|s'$|'$).
```

I need the first group. However what is happening with this pattern is a word like `cats'` matches with the third pattern i.e `'$`. Hence my `group(1)` still has `cats`. I tried using the pattern:

```
(\\w+)('s$|s'$|([^s] & '$).
```

But here what happens is for a word `abc'` group 1 has just `ab` and group 2 has `c'`. Any suggestions on how to handle this.

Comment: It's not very clear what you actually want. Can you post some sample input, and output?

Comment: i need to strip the apostrophe and the 's' from strings ie both 's and s'. Also any word that ends with '. Eg cats' shud be cat and cat's shud be cat and cat' should be cat.

Comment: Actually for the pattern (\\w+)('s$|s'$|'$) is there any way i can give priorities to 's$ s'$ '$ because currently cats' is being considered as a '$ case and not s'$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this maybe?

```
(\\w+)s?'(?:s\\b)?
```

And replace by the first capture group, or use a lookbehind:

```
(?<=\\w)s?'(?:s\\b)?
```

I used a word boundary to indicate that there is no more letters after `s` which I think was what you were trying to do with the `$` and space.

```
cats cat's cats'
```

Become:

```
cat cat cat
```

EDIT: Since you want to keep `cat'` as `cat'`:

```
(?<=\\w)(?:s'|'s\\b)
```

`cats cat's cats' cat'` becomes `cat cat cat cat'`.

Comment: I also need cat' to stay as cat.

Comment: @that_me123 Updated regex. See if the last one works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the input/output are supposed to be exactly (see Rohit's comment), but a solution involving `String.replaceAll` (takes regex `String` as argument) could go like:

```
String input = "cats cat's cats' dawgs";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("'s?\\W", " "));
```

Output:

```
cats cat cats dawgs
```

Comment: I need to remove the 's' as well.